# Jenkins Declarative pipeline: portion of sh command following double hyphen '--' not executed

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to jenkins and working on a declarative pipeline that runs an AWS cloudformation stack. The parameters to be passed to the stack have been declared in a previous stage. 
The issue is that the portion of the command after rendering a variable, and beginning with double hyphen '--' does not get picked up by jenkins.

This is the stage i have:

```
stage('Run Cloudformation') {
        steps {
            script {
                if(env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master') {
                        sh """
                            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
                            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} \
                            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2 \
                            aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stack-name \
                            --template-body ${template} \
                            --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=${keyname} ParameterKey=Region,ParameterValue=${region} 
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the error i get on jenkins console output is:[image]

I've tried changing the order of the template and parameter inputs, but the portion of the command following the rendered variable and beginning with a '--' gets skipped every time.

Appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Put `echo "${keyname}"`before `sh` to check if parameter not empty

Comment: Does ${template} contain any new lines by any chance? Can you also provide the output when you switch --template-body and --parameters

Comment: @Sers: I've done an echo on each of the variables in a previous stage, and none are empty

Comment: @KasunGajasinghe: Yes! that was the issue, i did a trim on the variables and it went through! Thank you very much :)